# When the menu opens, React-select freezes according to the list of countries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select, usetransition

I am using React Select and there is an API in which I get the countries list. In API there are 256 countries code. The user has to choose the country. But the screen freezes when menu is open. The reason is flag images. I use `react-world-flag`. And all images download.

I think if I use `useTransition` hook, I solve my problem. But I am not sure. If you have solution, answer this.

My codes

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { useTransition, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import Flag from "react-world-flags";

const ReactSelectFlag = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get("v1/countries").then(res => {
      setCountries(res.data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleGet = () => {
    startTransition(() => setMenuIsOpen(true));
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={countries}
      getOptionValue={option => option?.id}
      menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      onMenuOpen={handleGet}
      onMenuClose={() => setMenuIsOpen(false)}
      getOptionLabel={option => (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "6px" }}>
            <Flag code={option?.code} width="24px" height="14px" />
          </span>{" "}
          {option?.code} - {option?.name}{" "}
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default ReactSelectFlag;
```

this code works but when I click the button dropdown does not appear. After success rendering the options open. I want when I click the button, options have to open and after rendering all flags have to show.

Comment: Could you check if network request `GET v1/countries` succeeds and gives back the desired data? Open the web-browser developer tools, go to the network tab and find the `countries` request. Check the response status code and the response body. I suspect the URL should be `/v1/countries`, not `v1/countries`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r api returns 200. There is no problem with the API. It was an example api

Comment: I still think there is something wrong with loading/setting the `countries` state. When I copy your code and change `countries` into a predefined array everything seems to work fine. Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/77514176-3982562-01?file=app%2Fpage.jsx)

Comment: @3limin4t0r because your array length is 3, I added 256 countries to your array and I got same freezing

Comment: The amount of countries in the `countries` variable should not matter. Unless there are so many you're causing memory/processor issues for the OS running the browser. Here is the same MVP, but with 249 counties loaded instead of 3: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/77514176-3982562-02?file=app%2Fpage.jsx) Note that `countries` is still a statically defined variable and not loaded through a HTTP-request. Therefore I still think that there is something wrong with the `countries` assignment.

Comment: Does `console.log(countries)` before `return (<Select>...</Select>)` log the desired data? Does `console.log(res.data.data)` before `setCountries(res.data.data)` log the desired data?